# Запуск установщика с параметрами из командной строки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, install

У меня есть web-служба и я сделал для неё установщик.В установщике пользователь указывает Site, Virtual directory, Application Pool (стандартная форма установщика) и ещё два текстовых параметров (форма добавлена в установщик мной).

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы установщик можно было запустить из под командной строки с параметрами и его пользовательский интерфейс вообще не отображался?

Comment: Веб-служба - это служба операционной системы ОС windows? Что за установщик вы использовали? Это какой-то самописный installer или что-то стандартное?

Comment: Нет, это скорее сайт, устанавливается и отображается в IIS. Установщик создал сам в VS, переопределил метод Install в отдельном проекте и дописал работу с параметрмми, которые вводит пользователь при установке. При создании установщика для веб службы через стандартный проект Web Setup Project параметры Site, Virtual directory, Application Pool являются обязательными (как я понял) и форма для их ввода появляется в установщике сама.